# Update data from database on click of button

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a kendo dropdown and on selected id value i want to update data of particular row from database on button click event.but my dat is not updating and the old values are shown again and again.Please suggest me how to do it.
My code is

```
<script src="Js/jquery1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="CSS/kendo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#multi").kendoDropDownList();
    $("#editor").kendoEditor();
 });
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
   Select Template: <select id="multi" runat="server"></select>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  Template Name: <input type="text" id="txtName" name="Name" runat="server" />
</div>
<div>
Description:<textarea name="comments" id="txtComment" cols="25" rows="5"   
runat="server"></textarea>
<br />
</div>
<div>
Active: <input type="checkbox" id="chkActive" name="vehicle" runat="server" />
</div>
<div id="example" class="k-content">
<textarea id="editor" rows="10" cols="30" style="width:740px;height:440px"   
runat="server"></textarea>
</div>
<div>

<button type="button" id="btnUpdate" runat="server"   onserverclick="    
btnUpdate_onclick" >Save</button>

</div>
</form>
</body>
```

My .cs code is

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    Bind();
}

private void Bind()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ST0022;Initial 
Catalog=QuickMove_Globe;User ID=sa;Password=good");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Templates", con);
    con.Open();
    da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    multi.DataTextField = "ID";
    multi.DataValueField = "Name";
    multi.DataValueField = "Description";

    multi.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    multi.DataBind();
}

protected void btnUpdate_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ST0022;Initial 
Catalog=QuickMove_Globe;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=good");
    SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("Update_Temp", con);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    //passing parameters
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(multi.SelectedIndex));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",Convert.ToString(txtName.Value));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Convert.ToString(txtComment.Value));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", Convert.ToString(editor.Value));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", (chkActive.Value).ToString());

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    da.UpdateCommand=cmd;
    con.Open();






    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether correct value from dropdown is going to codebehind method or not. you may change the button command like below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" 
            onclick="btnUpdate_Click" Text="Save" />
```

Comment: But i am using html button. I have been told to do with html button only

Comment: after putting the breakpoint it is hitting the update code but changes are not made in the database. What i need to do? Please help me.

Comment: Can you post the content of the Update_Temp stored proc?

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE Update_Temp(@ID int,@Name varchar(100),@Description varchar(MAX),@Content nvarchar(MAX),@Active bit)
 
AS
 update Templates set 
 Name=@Name,
  Description=@Description,
 Content=@Content,Active=@Active where ID=@ID
 RETURN

Comment: how to create static array with parameters as id and name

Comment: as you are trying to update based on dropdown value, please check in the code behind by placing a breakpoint that, the value sending from the dropdown is really existing in the particular database table.

Comment: for creating static array in C# you can use Dictionary or HashTable of namespace system.collection. and in jquery you may create array as: var arr=[{id:'1', name:'r'},{id:'2',name:'n'}];

Answer (score 0):

You may want to think about adding some error handling but try this. You dont need the RETURN in the Stored Proc.  Other things you need to do is sort out your bind.  You are binding the wrong values to the dropdown.  Value needs to be ID and Text whatever you want displayed.  Then in the update Convert.ToInt32(multi.SelectedIndex) should be the SelectedValue not the SelectedIndex.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       Bind();
    }

}



        protected void btnUpdate_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ST0022;Initial 
 Catalog=QuickMove_Globe;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=good");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update_Temp", con);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //passing parameters
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(multi.SelectedIndex));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Convert.ToString(txtName.Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Convert.ToString(txtComment.Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", Convert.ToString(editor.Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", (chkActive.Value).ToString());
        con.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        Bind();
    }
```

Comment: You page load doesnt make much sense either.  It looks like you are calling an Update SP to fill a datareader.

Comment: take the whole If block out of the page load or wrap it in a if (!IsPostBack) Before the update occurs your page is repopulating the controls.

Comment: when i added !ispostback in page load only first id is updating again and again.no selected id is updated.What to do? please help me

Comment: selectedvalue property is not defined in html control.It is generating error.Can i pass static array to control

Comment: Change your whole page to an ASPX page.  It will be much easier for you and make more sense.

Comment: Sir please give me a solution that can i pass id and name in static array. How to create the static array